# new comer issue: will it work that java 5 run a jar file which is built by jdk6 or higher?

Tags: jar, netty

A straightforward issue for java new comer:
IMO, Java should keep backward compatible, so a jar built with JDK5 should work on JRE6 or high environment, but the converse case should fail.

However from the netty page, 
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/netty-4.0.17.Final, 
I found the following:

You require the following to build Netty:
Latest stable Oracle JDK 7
Latest stable Apache Maven
Note that this is build-time requirement. JDK 5 (for 3.x) or 6 (for 4.0+) is enough to run your Netty-based application.

This really confuses me, could anyone can help explain this?

Comment: it says that even thought JDK-7 is required to build it, once compiled  the bytecode is JRE-5 complient. As for why JRE-5 can run it but not compile it, we need to look at the build process itself. There is much more than just compilation. are there any Ant build script?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you specified proper `-source` and `-target` option to the `javac`.  Netty's `pom.xml` specifies `-source 1.5` and `-target 1.5` to ensure that.